# Few questions about Visual Studio 2015 Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I started to use Git provided in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. My team consists of only me. My needs are simple: to have history of changes, and possibility to revert them. Visual Studio created automatically local repository in my solution directory. My questions are:

1. Is it valid way to use only local repository? Will it create any problems when I never set up remote repository?
2. Is .git folder created in solution directory independent? I mean, does it have complete git information, so when I copy to another directory or machine, it will have its own full state?
3. In case of backups, will be there any difference between: a) simply setting a 3rd party program to backup whole solution directory to remote server. b) setting up server for remote repository, and backuping by commiting changes.
4. Why .git folder is hidden?
5. How can I hide field showing number of unpublished commits, which is located on the right bottom in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2? If I will never set up remote server, this number will increase to huge numbers, and reminds me about elapsing time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it's valid. The only problem with not having a remote repository is that if your computer fails, you've basically lost the code and the history.
2. Yes. The .git folder maintains all the information.
3. To me it feels that the only problem with backing up by simply "copy pasting" the entire folder into a server is that if the repository is big (either because of the number of files or the number of commits), you'll lose time copying everything over. Regularly pushing your changes to a remote git server is a lot faster and more secure (what if you lose your computer in between full backups?). Also, if you only have a dumb server that doesn't serve the files, how will you handle collaboration? You'll need a git server.
4. So you don't mess with your project's history.
5. I don't know about the number you're talking about here. A screenshot would help.